# Validation of UI Checklist

Tags: validation, user-interface

I have usability related checks (eg: there has to be calender beside every date field) to be done for multiple projects. I may not know the technology being used. Given that what is the best way to start.

I was thinking if i can use a tester tool to accomplish this task. Do you have any suggestions

Comment: may be this helps you http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/25/jquery-ui-and-validation/

Comment: Did'nt work in terms of solving the problem as i do not have control over the application that is being written except for the fact that it is a web application.Planning to extract htmls from Selenium and run validations on them.

Answer (score 0):

Planning to use Selenium to get the htmls at every html page and write a parser to run the validations on it. This decision is because i do not have control on the web application neither do i have a control on the testing tool which is going to be used.